# JQuery, resize div height to new content after previously setting height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, overflow

I have a DIV element that initially has a height of 0 and opacity of o who's overflow is hidden, and it has some content in it.

```
<div style='height: 0px; opacity: 0px; display: none; overflow: hidden; border: 1px solid #000;' id='mydiv'>
    Some Content<br><br>
    Lots or more content
    <br><br><br><br>
    hello world and stuff
</div>
```

I am fading this DIV into view when you click a button, the code that fades it into view is inside a function and is the following:

```
function fadediv(){
    mycontentheight=$('$mydiv')[0].scrollHeight;
    $('$mydiv').
        css('display','block').
        animate({opaicty:1,height:mycontentheight},100);
}
```

But then I want to add or remove some content from the DIV, for example:

```
document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML += 'Some more content...';
```

When I add the new content or take some content away, the height of the div doesn't change, and I would expect this. It's been set with the jquery in the function above and I have the overflow set to hidden, so more content would be in the overflow of the element, this makes sense.

But I want to change the height of the div to be the height of the new content, and I can't figure out how to do this. I've tried the following and it doesn't work:

```
function addtodiv(){
    document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML += 'Some more content...';
    mycontentheight=$('$mydiv')[0].scrollHeight;
    $('$mydiv').
        animate({opaicty:1,height:mycontentheight},100);
}
```

the above function adds the new content to the div, fine, but it doesn't update the height of the div to the height of the new content.

am I doing something wrong? am i missing something?

thank you for your help!

Comment: why don't you use the $(#"mydiv").append() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a few spelling mistakes, such as `opaicty` instead of `opacity`. You can find those and correct them yourself, since they are not relevant to the question. The main mistake you are making is that you are never updating the div size, which I did in `updateSizing`. You also need to select the specific div from the jQuery selector using `[0]` when using `innerHTML`, since it is not a jQuery method. Check out these changes on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewgu/carLafkf/).

Comment: thank you! sorry about the spelling mistakes :S. your method works for me.